# How to align key-value pairs inside SWT.MULTI Text?

Tags: swt

I want to show inside SWT Text key-value pairs, each pair on a separate row. How can I align the value "column" to start from the same place.

It is mandatory to use Text SWT.MULTI, SWT.READ_ONLY for this because the information needs to be selected and to have context menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no very good way to do this with `Text` which has very limited support for formatting, but you could try using tabs:

```
Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY);

text.setTabs(10);

text.setText("Line 1 Col 1\tLine 1 Col 2\nLine 2 Col 1\tLine 2 Col 2");
```

But this will be difficult to get right if the text in the columns varies in length a lot.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I combine adding spaces to match the max length of the first column and then add '\t'. It's not ideal but I seems to work for my case.